# If $G$ is p-nilpotent then $G$ has only one p-Sylow. Is it true?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let be $G$ a group p-nilpotent. So $G$ has a p-normal complement $H$ that is a $p'$ Hall subgroup.

I have read that if $G$ has a p-complement $H$ then this $H$ is unique.

I don't understand: the p-complement is unique when I have fixed a p-Sylow P?

If $H$ is the same p-complement for every Slow then should't I have that the p-sylow is normal?

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is $p$-nilpotent, say $G=PN$, with $N \unlhd G$, $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $P \cap N=1$, then for every conjugate $P^g$, the subgroup $N$ is also a complement. For $G^g=(PN)^g=P^gN^g=P^gN$, since $N$ is normal. Similarly, $1^g=1=(P \cap N)^g=P^g \cap N^g=P^g \cap N$. 
The complement $N$ is unique. If $M$ is another one, then $|M|=|N|$, and $P \cong G/N \geq MN/N \cong M/(M \cap N)$. So $M/(M \cap N)$ is both a $p$- and $p'$-group, whence trivial, from which $M=N$ follows.